# Как создать свою клавиатуру

Tags: android

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при вводе в EditText клавиатура показывала не весь набор символов алфавита, а только те символы, которые есть в переменной String.
Здесь как то сделано[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ты можешь кстати заморочиться и сделать немного не `EditText`, а свой `View`, при нажатии на который будешь открывать снизу свою `Layout` клавиатуры поверх `Layout` активности, в которой сделаешь кнопочки своего стиля, при нажатии на которые на твоём `View` будет добавляться буква кнопочки (`mView.setText(mView.getText().toString() + "A");` при нажатии на букву А, и т.д.). Если хочешь я могу заморочиться тебе это сделать за пару дней, реально не плохой вариант. Тогда объяви свой вопрос конкурсным.

Answer (score 1):

Легко и непринужденно:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="0123456789.abcdefgh" //клавиатура покажет только эти символы 
/>
```

Можно то же самое установить и программно - чуть замороченнее, но результат будет тем же.

Comment: а мне как раз очень нужно программно, как сделать программно?

Answer (score 0):

editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdef"));

Передаются `digits` программно

Answer (score -1):

К сожалению — нет.
Для этого необходимо создать свою клавиатуру и убедиться, что пользователь выбрал её в качестве основной — но не думаю, что этот вариант Вам подходит.

Comment: я скриншот приложил, они както сделали для каждого вопроса новый набор слов в клаве. И это не единственного приложение